# Put a counter in batch apex class

Tags: batch, stateful

I have a batch class in which i need to put a counter to count all the records that are processed successfully.
My code is as follows:

```
 global class BatchUpdate implements Database.Batchable<sObject>,Database.Stateful {

    global final String Query;  
    public Integer total=0;
        global BatchUpdate(String q) {  
            Query=q;
        }  


   global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
        return Database.getQueryLocator('SELECT id,b.LastModifiedDate from Base_Catalogue__c b');
   }

   global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, list<sObject> scope){


        List<Base_Catalogue__c> bc1 = new List<Base_Catalogue__c>();
        List<BC_Count__c> count = [select BC_count_AP08__c from BC_Count__c];
        system.debug('The total count records from the Ap08 server: '+ count);

        system.debug('Start of the program');
        for (sObject s : scope) {
            Base_Catalogue__c bc2 =(Base_Catalogue__c)s;
            DateTime d=bc2.LastModifiedDate; 
            Date lastdate = date.newinstance(d.year(), d.month(), d.day());
            system.debug('Hi2::'+lastdate);

            DateTime dT = System.Today();
            Date today = date.newinstance(dT.year(), dT.month(), dT.day());
            system.debug('Hi3:::'+today);

             if(lastdate==today){
             system.debug('check');
              bc2.Check__c=true;  
              total++;

              }
              else
              {
              bc2.Check__c=false;
              }    
              bc1.add(bc2);

              system.debug('The total count records from the Ap08 server: '+ count);
        for(BC_Count__c var: count)
        {
            var.BC_count_AP08__c = total;
            update var;

        }

        }
        update bc1;


       }
       global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC)
       {
           System.debug(LoggingLevel.Info, 'Your info');
           system.debug('COUNT::::'+total);
           if(!Test.isRunningtest()){
           //Updating all the Detail object records to point to Active Base Catalogue
           UpdateDetailReference udr = new UpdateDetailReference();
           Database.executebatch(udr,200);
           }

       }
    }
```

"total" is the counter that I've put. and when the  bc2.Check__c is evaluated to true, that's when the counter should be incremented. I want to to use this counter value as a field in a object. The system.debug value is showing the correct value. However, The field BC_count_AP08__c is showing a value of 0. I think I am not assigning the value correctly.

Comment: The count should be in which specific record of the object?  There will be many records.

Comment: The count is supposed to come in the BC_Count object that I've created. In that, the field BC count AP08 is supposed to be updated with the value of the counter "count".

Comment: are you sure that there are records returned by query

Comment: Yes yes! this a fully functional class already running! Why do u ask?

Comment: Younus -- re: `urgent` -- exhortations to the community are not well-received. Please [edit] your question as well as cleaning up your use of a variable name considered an English language vulgarism.

Comment: Hi everyone! apologize for the inconvenience caused! I've cleaned up the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although there are certain unclear things, still I would like to suggest below answer:

```
global class BatchUpdate implements Database.Batchable<sObject>,Database.Stateful {

    global final String Query;  
    public Integer total=0;
        global BatchUpdate(String q) {  
            Query=q;
        }  


   global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
        return Database.getQueryLocator('SELECT id,b.LastModifiedDate from Base_Catalogue__c b');
   }

   global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, list<sObject> scope){


        List<Base_Catalogue__c> bc1 = new List<Base_Catalogue__c>();
        system.debug('Start of the program');
        for (sObject s : scope) {
            Base_Catalogue__c bc2 =(Base_Catalogue__c)s;
            DateTime d=bc2.LastModifiedDate; 
            Date lastdate = date.newinstance(d.year(), d.month(), d.day());
            system.debug('Hi2::'+lastdate);

            DateTime dT = System.Today();
            Date today = date.newinstance(dT.year(), dT.month(), dT.day());
            system.debug('Hi3:::'+today);

             if(lastdate==today){
             system.debug('check');
              bc2.Check__c=true;  
              total++;

              }
              else
              {
              bc2.Check__c=false;
              }    
              bc1.add(bc2);           

        }
        update bc1;


       }
       global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC)
       {
           List<BC_Count__c> count = [select BC_count_AP08__c from BC_Count__c];
           for(BC_Count__c var: count)          {
                var.BC_count_AP08__c = total;
                }
           update count;
           system.debug('The total count records from the Ap08 server: '+ count);
           System.debug(LoggingLevel.Info, 'Your info');
           system.debug('COUNT::::'+total);
           if(!Test.isRunningtest()){
           //Updating all the Detail object records to point to Active Base Catalogue
           UpdateDetailReference udr = new UpdateDetailReference();
           Database.executebatch(udr,200);
           }

       }
    }
```

Below are reasons of Edit:

1. You can maintain a count variable throughout the batch scope and then update by single DML in finish. There is no need to save DML in every batch.
2. I have removed a DML that occurred within two loops. There were chances of failure because of governor limits.